# How to create word selector to select and highlight and remov selected words from text?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I need to create a word selector and get result from it. For example you have some text like one string, that I can probably parse with white spaces to array, but I have no idea, how to create mechanism for selecting some words from text that are highlighted after clicking on any word, and after that be able to obtain information which words from text were highlighted.

Imagine you are user and want after showing page with text to choose any words to highlight, and after clicking button a system for example will delete these words from this text, these highlighted words. It is not needful to see this change for user after deleting of highlighted words, but is important for system-backend. I cannot remove words one by one, but I have to choose some specific words, and press button and system should be able to work further with text without those words. Furthermore, after another tap/click on selected word, word should be disselected.

[image: Problem example, choose words and clear text]

Is there any method, framework(API) or anything that I missed during my long searching?

Comment: You can use any editor to make this. I know about `ckeditor` and `quill`, search to get selected text content from any one and make your own multiple drop down to confirm delete or deselect.

Comment: I've found something that may give you an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/Lad1dp18/1/

Comment: Ok, thank you Niklesh, I will try to make some miracle with that.

Comment: Thank you Krzysztof, nice to see some work with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found how to do it that man can understand it. Some work with text, parsing, creating span for every word or special char that can be removed, and thanks to jquery click words, highlight them, and multiple delete with fact that at the end I have string without previously selected words. I made it on my own, well, please if you think my logical approaches are somehow incorrect, you can comment it to make my implementation idea better, thanks.

The source code, wordChooser.html:

```js
//  text I will obtained from database
textToClear = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the \"1500s\", when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem             Ipsum.";

textAfterClear = ""

parseTextToWords();

function parseTextToWords(){
 // basic interpunct chars should be single elements to click
 textToClear = textToClear.replace(/\./g, ' .');
 textToClear = textToClear.replace(/\?/g, ' ?');
 textToClear = textToClear.replace(/\!/g, ' !');
 textToClear = textToClear.replace(/\,/g, ' ,');
 textToClear = textToClear.replace(/\"/g, ' " ');
 // removing multiple spaces for single
 textToClear = textToClear.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
 
 var words = textToClear.split(" ");

 // generate words with ids to change their future css
 for ( var i = 0, l = words.length; i < l; i++ ) {
  var word = $('<span />').attr({'id':'word'+i }).html(" "+words[i]);
  word.css('color','black');
  $('.clearText').append(word);
  
  $('#word'+i).click(function() { 
   if($(this).css('color') == "rgb(0, 0, 0)"){
    $(this).css('color','red');
   }else{
    $(this).css('color','black');
   }  
  });
 }
}

function removeSelected(){
 $('.clearText').find('*').each(function() {
      if($(this).css('color') == "rgb(0, 0, 0)"){
   textAfterClear += $(this).html();
  }
    });
 $(".clearText").html(textAfterClear);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<title>Word chooser</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="clearText" style="border: 1px solid darkorange;" >
</div>

<div align="center"><button  onclick="removeSelected()" type="submit">Delete Choosed</button></div>

</body>

</html>
```